# Jenkins Pipeline Artifactory Promotion for artifacts in multiple repositories

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

We are using Artifactory and Jenkins pipeline. One of our product publish in Artifactory a nuget in a nuget repository and a zip in a generic type repository. This is working fine, by when we want to use the interactive promotion functionality, to move our nuget into the release-nuget repo and our zip into the generic-release repo, it does not seems to handle correctly more than one repository.

The Artifactory documentation says : 
"You can add as many builds as you like, by using the method multiple times. All the builds added will be displayed in the promotion window. "

If i use the method multiple time, the target repos in the promotion window is empty and running the promotion give this message :

```
Promoting build ....
Performing dry run promotion (no changes are made during dry run) ...
{
  "messages" : [ {
    "level" : "INFO",
    "message" : "Skipping build item relocation: no target repository selected."
  } ]
}
Dry run finished successfully.
Performing promotion ...
{
  "messages" : [ {
    "level" : "INFO",
    "message" : "Skipping build item relocation: no target repository selected."
  } ]
}
Promotion completed successfully!
Completed
```

Is anyone have succeeded doing promotion for a build that use more than one repository in Artifactory ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

(1) First select a Build type (e.g. RPMS or SRPMS) from the drop-down box first, then press the "Load Build" button which shall
(2) populate the "Target" and "Source promotion repository" names, then if all good
(3) press the "Promote build" button, and then repeat for the other Build type.

If you're looking to promote multiple artifacts to multiple target repositories from one jenkins job, it is currently not supported. You can follow either of the below options.
A. Refactor the artifacts as their own independently promotoble modules. OR
B. Do an automatic (conditional) promotion during pipeline build. OR
C. select each build infos separately, load and promote them like given in point (1).